# Traverse tree collecting nodes combinations

Tags: java, algorithm, tree

Summary: I have a tree, containing car parts, from which I need to build all valid combinations of these parts.

Parts can be required - every build must contain them.

Parts can be optional.

Parts can conflict with other parts.

Parts can have optional parts inside them.

Example tree:

```
Car
| - Motor (required)
| - - V8
| - - V12
| - - - Colour (optional)
| - - - - Black
| - - - - Chrome
| - Transmission (required)
| - - Mechanical
| - - Automatic
| - Wheels (optional)
| - - Basic
| - - Fancy
| - - - Colour (optional)
| - - - - Red
| - - - - Blue
| - BodyStyle (optional)
| - - Hatchback (conflicts with Motor.V12)
| - - Buggy (conflicts with Motor.V8)
```

Valid builds for this tree:

```
Car | Motor.V8 | Transmission.Automatic
Car | Motor.V8 | Transmission.Automatic | Wheels.Basic
Car | Motor.V12.Colour.Black | Transmission.Automatic | Wheels.Basic
Car | Motor.V8 | Transmission.Automatic | BodyStyle.Hatchback
Car | Motor.V12 | Transmission.Mechanical | Wheels.Fancy | BodyStyle.Buggy
Car | Motor.V12 | Transmission.Mechanical | Wheels.Fancy.Colour.Red | BodyStyle.Buggy
```

In what direction should I move to solve this task?

This should be a relatively easy task, but I am struggling with where even to start.

Comment: Are you asking what data structure you should use to store all that data?

Comment: Perhaps generating all possible permutations with some patterns invalidated according to the rules.

Comment: @Goion I'm looking for algorithms, that I can use here, or code solving this task

Answer (score 0):

Given you are asking how to start, here is a suggestion:

1. Start with an interface that represents anything that you might need to query about a node
2. Write the simplest implementation of that interface (e.g. your 'Blue' leaf node). Include unit tests to make sure it does what you want.
3. Continue through the rest of the nodes until they all do what you expect.
4. Now write an entirely new class that generates all your variants, using only the interface methods.